# How to set spring bootstrap.properties at execution time

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-config

Is it possible to set the contents of Spring's bootstrap.properties at execution time?

I have a client application for Spring's cloud config which holds a line to point to the config server:

```
spring.cloud.config.url = http://localhost:8888
```

And I would like to set this config. I tried setting it like application.properties can be set:

```
java -jar ./config-client.jar --spring.cloud.config.url=http://localhost:8888
```

But it didn't work. So my question is, how can I set this property at execution time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be caused by wrong properties name. `url` should be `uri`. 
Try to change your property in bootstrap.properties like below.

```
spring.cloud.config.uri = http://localhost:8888
```

And then try again like below.

```
java -jar ./config-client.jar --spring.cloud.config.uri=<something else>
```

`http://localhost:8888` is the default value of `spring.cloud.config.uri`. That's probably the reason why you didn't recognize the wrong property name.